# how to save a sprite to a playerPref?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have three scenes.
1) Where you make your team.
2) Where the level is built.
3) The game.

On my team, there are 5 choices for each team member.
I am trying to figure out how I set the player and then recall the `Image` or `Sprite` of that player on another scene.

I figured a `playerPref` would work, but it seems like this is not an option.

What is a good way of saving an image from one scene and recalling the image in a different scene?

Answer (score 4):

You can store texture of sprite as base64 in playerprefs, then you can create sprite from stored texture. But texture must be Read/Write Enabled and supported format like ARGB32, RGBA32, RGB24 etc. Here is an example;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TextureStore
{

    public static void WriteTextureToPlayerPrefs (string tag, Texture2D tex)
    {
        // if texture is png otherwise you can use tex.EncodeToJPG().
        byte[] texByte = tex.EncodeToPNG ();

        // convert byte array to base64 string
        string base64Tex = System.Convert.ToBase64String (texByte);

        // write string to playerpref
        PlayerPrefs.SetString (tag, base64Tex);
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();
    }

    public static Texture2D ReadTextureFromPlayerPrefs (string tag)
    {
        // load string from playerpref
        string base64Tex = PlayerPrefs.GetString (tag, null);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (base64Tex)) {
            // convert it to byte array
            byte[] texByte = System.Convert.FromBase64String (base64Tex);
            Texture2D tex = new Texture2D (2, 2);

            //load texture from byte array
            if (tex.LoadImage (texByte)) {
                return tex;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty cool actually, especially if you want to send a custom texture over the network.

Answer (score 0):

You could just save the name of the sprite to PlayerPrefs, and then load it from resources: `Resources.Load(spriteName);`

Comment: so save it as a string?

Comment: @TimCooley yes exactly.

Comment: GetComponentInChildren<Sprite>().name  I am now trying to capture the name of the sprite.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a static texture variable. write texture of the image to that variable and read it on the other scene